# DependencyProperty of Custom Type won't fire propertychanged callback

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

Premise: I read all the others threads about similar issues but none of those solved my problem.

I have a UserControl (SummarySource) with 3 DP:

```
public static DependencyProperty QueryProperty;
public static DependencyProperty MaxRowsPerPageProperty;
public static DependencyProperty OpcSessionProperty;
```

And the respective public getters and setters:

```
[Category("Common")]
public String Query
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(QueryProperty); }
    set { SetValue(QueryProperty, value); }
}

[Category("Common")]
public UInt32 MaxRowsPerPage
{
    get { return (UInt32)GetValue(MaxRowsPerPageProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MaxRowsPerPageProperty, value); }
}

[Category("Common")]
public UaSession OpcSession
{
    get { return (UaSession)GetValue(OpcSessionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(OpcSessionProperty, value); }
}
```

The problem is that tha PropertyChanged Callback for the "OpcSession" variable (the only one that is a custom type) isn't fired.

### Static Constructor

```
OpcSessionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OpcSession", typeof(UaSession), typeof(SummarySource), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSessionChanged)));
```

### The Callback

```
private static void OnSessionChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("He3e1");
    SummarySource thisControl = (SummarySource)sender;
    if (thisControl.DataContext != null)
    {
       ((DataRetriever)thisControl.DataContext).SetOpcSession((UaSession)e.NewValue);
    }
 }
```

The MessageBox is never showed. If I put a MessageBox.Show on the other callbacks I can see the message when Load the form that use the control or change the value in xaml.

### The .Xaml

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <cs:UaSession x:Name="opcSession" EndpointUrl="opc.tcp://192.168.200.11:62543/Runtime"/>
</Window.DataContext>

<control:SummarySource x:Key="qq" MaxRowsPerPage="25" OpcSession="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=window, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

No Binding Errors in output